# Facing issue with setCustomAnimations() while replacing fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-fragmentactivity, android-framework

I have 2 fragments A and B. I am replacing the fragment B with A, and setting `setCustomAnimations(right_to_left, fadein, fadeout, left_to_right)`. Fragment B is behaving correctly like it is coming from right to left and on pressing <kbd>Back</kbd> button and do pop back stack it is leaving from left to right. But no animation happens to the fragment A its doesn't fade in and fade out.

*Note*: I have tried it with creating the sample application and it works perfectly fine but when I implement the same thing into my project it behaves as above. What mistake am I making while implementing the `setCustomAnimation()` in the my project?

I have already tried:

1. have a latest support library
2. `hardwareAccelarated="true"` in the manifest file
3. add `setCustomAnimation()` before `replace()` method
4. compile it with above 3.0

I doubt there can be an issue with the framework my app is built on but not sure. Can anyone please let me know what else I can check to make it work?

Comment: Hey guys i have got what was the issue and i am sharing this may help others. I was actually replacing the Fragment B with the different layout ( what we set in the xml for replacing fragments ) and fragment A was replaced with the different fragment.Thats why transitions for fragment B was not happening. For these transitions to happen B fragment has to be replaced with the same layout which A has been replaced.

Comment: I am also facing problem with replace i am able to set transition and they are working only thing is that the fragment which is going replace gets loaded before transition. I do have all the points mentioned in questions.

Comment: @Siddhesh hey can you elaborate what do mean>

Comment: suppose there are two fragments A and B. A if currently on screen now i press next button fragment B suddenly appears in place of fragment A and after than animation starts it sets correct fragment.

Comment: @Siddhesh so what do u say it's a bug or something?

Comment: yes i think so its a bug